Excel - Calculate working days based on multiple date range for a group
Need to calculate distinct working days based on multiple activities (Sub tasks) for a group (Year Month)



Sr No
Yr Mon
Start Date
End Date
Distinct Countable Days In Month




1
Jun-24
6/10/2024
6/11/2024



2
Jun-24
6/12/2024
6/12/2024



3
Jun-24
6/13/2024
6/16/2024



4
Jun-24
6/12/2024
6/18/2024



5
Jun-24
6/19/2024
6/21/2024
10


6
Jul-24
7/3/2024
7/5/2024



7
Jul-24
7/8/2024
7/11/2024



8
Jul-24
7/8/2024
7/11/2024



9
Jul-24
7/9/2024
7/11/2024



10
Jul-24
7/3/2024
7/11/2024
7



enter image description here
As Above - Expecting the last column as output

You forgot to explain the logic

Will it never be the case that Start Date and End Date are in different months? If they are in different months, how would you want the output displayed since your Yr Mon column display might be fubar'd.

I put your data in A1:D11.

To count working days in Jun/2024, you can use below:
=LET(
    dates, SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2024, 6, 1), 0)), 1, DATE(2024, 6, 1)),
    isWorkingDays, MAP(
        dates,
        LAMBDA(d, OR(($C$2:$C$6 <= d) * ($D$2:$D$6 >= d)) * NETWORKDAYS(d, d))
    ),
    SUM(isWorkingDays)
)

To count working days in July/2024:
=LET(
    dates, SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2024, 7, 1), 0)), 1, DATE(2024, 7, 1)),
    isWorkingDays, MAP(
        dates,
        LAMBDA(d, OR(($C$7:$C$11 <= d) * ($D$7:$D$11 >= d)) * NETWORKDAYS(d, d))
    ),
    SUM(isWorkingDays)
)

Below list all dates in June 2024:
=SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2024, 6, 1), 0)), 1, DATE(2024, 6, 1))
OR(($C$2:$C$6 <= d) * ($D$2:$D$6 >= d)) * NETWORKDAYS(d, d)checks whether a given date is within any of the [start date, end date] bracket, and is a working day.

Here is one possible way:


=LET(
     a,A2:A11,
     b,B2:B11,
     MAP(a,b,LAMBDA(c,d,
     LET(e,FILTER(C2:D11,b=d),
         f,MMULT(e,{-1;1})+1,
         g,SEQUENCE(,MAX(f)),
         IF(MAX((b=d)*a)=c,
         SUM(--(MOD(UNIQUE(TOCOL(TAKE(e,,1)+g/(g<=f)-1,3)),7)>1)),"")))))


One more alternative:
=LET(
     a, B2:B11,
     b, C2:C11,
     c, D2:D11,
     d, UNIQUE(a),
     e, XLOOKUP(d,a,b),
     f, XLOOKUP(d,a,c,,,-1),
     g, MAP(e,f,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(u, SEQUENCE(,y-x+1,x),
                       SUM(UNIQUE(TOCOL((b>=u)*(u<=c)*NETWORKDAYS(x,y))))))),
     h, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
     IF(XLOOKUP(a,a,h,,,-1)=h,XLOOKUP(a,d,g),0))



Mad e a minor edit on the date as date in last 3 were incorrect and output was incorrect .. Please check and let me know

@NikyRathod updated older formula as well as added another alternative.

I don't know if this is a possibility, but if your Start and End dates happen to be in separate months, then your yr-month column is undefined for the overlapping range.
One way of solving this is by using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WorkingTbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Sr No", Int64.Type}, {"Start Date", type date}, {"End Date", type date}}),
    #"Date Lists" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "all Dates", each 
        List.Dates([Start Date],Duration.Days([End Date]-[Start Date])+1,#duration(1,0,0,0)), type {date}),

//combine lists
// remove duplicates and Sat/Sun
// could also remove Holidays if had a list
    #"Combine Date Lists" = List.Sort(List.Select(List.Distinct(List.Combine(#"Date Lists"[all Dates])), each 
        Date.DayOfWeek(_) <> Day.Saturday and Date.DayOfWeek(_) <> Day.Sunday),Order.Ascending),

//Create table for output
    #"Working Days" = Table.FromColumns({#"Combine Date Lists"},type table[workdays=date]),

//Group by Month
    #"Group Months" = Table.Group(#"Working Days","workdays",{
        {"Month-Yr", each Date.ToText([workdays]{0}, "MMMM-yyyy"), type text},
        {"Workdays in Month", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}},
        GroupKind.Local,(x,y)=>Number.From(Date.Month(x) <> Date.Month(y))
    ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group Months",{"workdays"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"



With start/end spanning months

Handling case Ron commented on, logic is similar to rachel's.
Get all dates in columns and select based on workday and start/end
Include if the the count is positive

=LET(
    data, $A$2:INDEX($B$2:$B$100, COUNTA($A$2:$A$100)),
    start, INDEX(data, , 1),
    end, INDEX(data, , 2),
    dates, SEQUENCE(, DAYS(MAX(end), MIN(start)) + 1, MIN(start)),
    is_workday, NETWORKDAYS(dates, dates),
    include, BYCOL(
        IF(is_workday * (start <= dates) * (dates <= end), 1, 0),
        LAMBDA(for_day, IF(SUM(for_day), 1, 0))
    ),
    count_by_months, REDUCE(
        {"Month-Year", "Distinct Countable Days In Month"},
        SORT(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(VSTACK(start, end), 0))),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            VSTACK(
                acc,
                HSTACK(
                    TEXT(cur, "mmm-yyyy"),
                    SUM(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(include), EOMONTH(cur, 0) = EOMONTH(TRANSPOSE(dates), 0)))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    count_by_months
)



Per OP
=LET(
    comment_1, "Using BYCOL",
    data, $B$2:INDEX($D$2:$D$1000, COUNTA($B$2:$B$1000)),
    yr_mon, INDEX(data, , 1),
    distinct_countable_work_days, LAMBDA(y_m,
        LET(
            for_y_m, FILTER(data, yr_mon = y_m),
            dates, DATE(YEAR(y_m), MONTH(y_m), SEQUENCE(, DAY(EOMONTH(y_m, 0)))),
            start, INDEX(for_y_m, , 2),
            end, INDEX(for_y_m, , 3),
            include, IF(NETWORKDAYS(dates, dates) * (start <= dates) * (dates <= end), 1, 0),
            SUM(BYCOL(include, LAMBDA(for_day, IF(SUM(for_day), 1, 0))))
        )
    ),
    REDUCE(
        "Distinct Countable Days In Month",
        UNIQUE(yr_mon),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            VSTACK(acc, EXPAND("", COUNTIF(yr_mon, cur) - 1, , ""), distinct_countable_work_days(cur))
        )
    )
)



This formula uses MAP function instead of BYROW because it cannot handle as required the string which is generated by TEXTJOIN
The formula is in cell E42  and drag down.
The FILTER and IF functions' range parameters should be adjusted to the actual range.
=LET(act,FILTER(C$42:D$51,B42=B$42:B$51),
days,MAP(CHOOSECOLS(act,1),CHOOSECOLS(act,2),
     LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,b-a+1,a)))),
tot,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,days),
uni,UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(tot,"|"))),
res,NETWORKDAYS(MIN(VALUE(uni)),MAX(VALUE(uni))),
IF(B42<>B43,res,""))

or with adjusted the UNIQUE function to columns
=LET(act,FILTER(C$42:D$51,B42=B$42:B$51),
days,MAP(CHOOSECOLS(act,1),CHOOSECOLS(act,2),
     LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SEQUENCE(1,b-a+1,a)))),
tot,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,days),
uni,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(tot,"|"),TRUE),
res,NETWORKDAYS(MIN(VALUE(uni)),MAX(VALUE(uni))),
IF(B42<>B43,res,""))


